# "Simulate" border-width on colgroup with IE7

Tags: css, html-table, internet-explorer-7

Suppose I have something like this:

```
<table class="myTable">
  <colgroup span="2" /><colgroup span="2" />
  <tr><td>........</tr>
```

And so on...

Then on the stylesheet:

```
table.myTable colgroup
{
    border-right: solid 5px #ffffff;
}
```

The point being that I want some space to separate colgroups in my table.

It's working fine in Firefox and IE8. I already read everywhere that IE7 does not implements borders for colgroup, but here is a call to your imagination and creativity, does anyone have an idea of how I could achieve a similar result in IE7, without adding a class to every cells or generating empty cell...

Here's an exemple of the result in Firefox 4 : http://imageshack.us/photo/my-images/853/capturezz.png/
The headers generated can be litterally of any form, some case are really complex. This is why the colgroup solution is interesting, since it is quite simple to calculate the needed span.

Every suggestions will be appreciated.

Comment: You mean `table.myTable colgroup`, right?

Comment: Just a thought, but I just realized that IE7 does not support borders for <tr> elements neither, so at least the behavior is coherent between rows and columns.

Answer (score 2):

Don't have much experience in IE7, but this might work:
You can check if it is possible to set a background-image. And align that image (with the desired color) to the right side of the cell, making some kind of a fake border look.

In chrome setting a border on a colgroup doesn't work eighter. Setting a background-image does work.

Greetz,

XpertEase

Comment: I got chrome 11 here and the border does work.
I dont see how setting a background image would help me... since I want to create some kind of "gap" between columns groups, setting a background image would just fill such a gap with appropriate color, but I still have to create this gap.
Or maybe I misunderstood your answer?

Comment: But why do you need a border then? Instead you could use a padding or margin.

Comment: Because that's quite a simple yet elegant way to get the result I want...
I added an image of an exemple of what is generated to my initial question.

Comment: However not possible...a background-image with the same color as the background-color of the table would do the trick. By aligning the image to the right side of the cell, repeating only vertically and setting a padding of 5px to the right of the cell, preventing the text in the cell from overlapping the background-image.

Comment: You're right, it's not possible with IE7...

But your solution, as I understand it, would result in adding a particular class to all tds that are on the _right edge_ of the colgroup, and this is exactly what I dont want to add in the algorithm...

Comment: Voted up, but I can't mark as answer since the question implied "without adding a class to every cells or generating empty cell"...

In my particular case, I preffer having the most elegant solution and losing the border for IE7 since it doesn't break functionnality.

Answer (score 0):

In order to use the border property in tables, you must set the following rule. If not you wont get them

```
table {
border-collapse:collapse;
}
```

Then you will get borders working as you pretend

Comment: Ooops. June 2011!!. I hope you are still coding !!! ja ja I was not aware of the date. Fantastic. Better to be late than not to be at all.

Comment: I answered this question when posting to an updated one . Very similar. Funny I did not realize I was posting it here.